# How to fetch endpoint data in SvelteKit after initial load?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an endpoint in my SvelteKit `(1.0.0-next.572)` application based on the [random number example](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) in their documentation. If I fetch data from that endpoint in my `+page.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let randomNumber = 0;
    async function random() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/random-number');
        randomNumber = await response.json();
    }
</script>

{randomNumber}

<button on:click={random}>random</button>
```

everything works fine, **but** I get this warning in my browser console:

> Loading /api/random-number using `window.fetch`. For best results, use
> the `fetch` that is passed to your `load` function:
> https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests

If I change the request from `GET` to `POST` the warning disappears. I just don't think that this is a `POST` request. I understand that data should be loaded in the `+page.ts` or `+page.server.ts`, but how to load it **after** the initial request when reacting to user events?

What's the idiomatic way here? I could imagine reloading the page or using a form action, but that seems unintuitive and cumbersome.

**update:**
It seems to be a bug / false positive. See discussion in answer. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/7992) now.

**update2**
This has been [fixed](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/commit/c4137536f2c6572eaeec1a82ccea0852f5be6b98) in svelte/kit 1.0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one data set that can be loaded using the `load` function, you can [`invalidate` it](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#invalidation-manual-invalidation) to make it reload when necessary.

For other use cases you can just use `fetch` on the page; the main advantage of using the `load` function is that it can be server-side rendered on initial load of the page.

Comment: ok, but should I just ignore the warning when using `fetch` then?

Comment: Looking at your code, it already only executed on `click`; I am surprised you get this warning. The warning is supposed to show up if you use `fetch` in the load function without referring to the `fetch` that is passed as part of the argument.

Comment: It's an empty skeleton project with just the endpoint from the docs and the page/component I provided in the question.

Comment: So you do not currently have a `load` function but still get the warning?

Comment: correct, I don't have a `load` function anywhere in my code. It's just `/routes/+page.svelte` and `/routes/api/random-number/+server.ts`.

Comment: This is probably a false positive/bug then. The code around the warning uses a heuristic to determine when to show the warning. Might be worth reporting with a full repro, maybe that could be improved.

Comment: thank you! i might open an issue for it
one thing I noticed: the first time I open my page after starting the dev server, the warning does not show. it only starts showing after reloading. so there might be a difference between ssr and csr.

Answer (score 1):

One way around making sure you do not get this warning until a fix happens could be to define your functions in the +page.ts and expose them in the data prop to be later called. Apologies cannot comment on previous answer as this is connected.

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ fetch, params }) {
    async function colourName(colourHex: string): Promise<string> {
        const response = await fetch(`https://www.thecolorapi.com/id?hex=${colourHex.slice(1)}`);

        const {
            name: { value: name }
        } = await response.json();

        return name;
    }  
    return { colourName };
}
```

And then your +page.svelte can

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */  
export let data;  

...
...

data.colourName(colourHex)
```

Comment: on the one hand i find the extra step via the load function a bit unintuitive. on the other hand it keeps my .svelte file nice and clean. i like the idea, thank you!